# Is the sequence $(\sin^{n}t)_{n \in {\Bbb{N}}}$ totally bounded in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, function-spaces

Is the sequence $(\sin^{n}t)_{n \in {\Bbb{N}}}$ totally bounded in the space $C[0,1]$ with the supremum metric?

By the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, this sequence is totally bounded if and only if it is uniformly  bounded and equicontinuous. It is uniformly bounded by $1$, so we can search for equicontinuity instead.

I believe that the sequence is equicontinuous, but I could not find a way to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arzelà-Ascoli and equicontinuity are useless. Let $A=\{\sin^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}.$ $(\sin^n)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$ (because $0\le\sin t\le\sin 1<1$), so $\bar A=A\cup\{0\}$ is compact, which proves that $A$ is totally bounded.